# Change background-color with different shades of color

Tags: javascript, html, css, background

I am trying to make a webpage with a background that changes color with the *shades* of the rainbow. I don't want any smooth transitions, I want them to change instantly. With shades, I mean it doesn't just go from red to orange to green e.t.c, I mean it uses the shades of each color.

It's a bit difficult to explain, I got it from [this](https://kutcijferblokka.de/) website. If you hit 'inspect element' on the log in page, and then visit console, you'll see a bunch of rainbow text. The code used to achieve this is:

```
background:linear-gradient(to left, red,orange,yellow,green,blue,indigo,violet)
```

As you can see there, it's a bunch of different shades from each color in the code. How would I use this, but as a background of my webpage?

Comment: you apply it to your body tag? or your top outer wrapper if you have one?

Comment: @slashsharp to my body tag

Comment: Can you add desired look as image?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov no, as the background changes color for example every 2 seconds

Answer (score 2):

To instantly change the background color we can do it using jquery.
See this link.

https://jsfiddle.net/9bcgw7x4/6/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var a = 1;
  var add =2;

  function changeBG(){
    var r = Math.floor((255 * a) / 100);  
    var g = Math.floor((255 * (100 - a)) / 100);
    var b = Math.floor((255 * a) / 100);  
    if(a<=0){
      add = 2;
    }else if(a>99){
      add=-2;
    }  
    a=a+add;    
    $('body').css('background-color', 'rgb('+r+','+g+','+b+')');
  }    
  setInterval(changeBG, 1000);

});
```

Comment: No, I don't want it to ease, I want it to change background instantly (it probably needs javascript)

Comment: Yes using javascript, now it will change the backgound color in each 1 second. https://jsfiddle.net/9bcgw7x4/6/

Answer (score 2):

background changing with all the shades of the rainbow:

```js
    setInterval(function () {
        document.body.style.background = "red";
        setTimeout(function () { document.body.style.background = "orange" }, 1000);
        setTimeout(function () { document.body.style.background = "yellow" }, 2000);
        setTimeout(function () { document.body.style.background = "green" }, 3000);
        setTimeout(function () { document.body.style.background = "blue" }, 4000);
        setTimeout(function () { document.body.style.background = "indigo" }, 5000);
        setTimeout(function () { document.body.style.background = "violet" }, 6000);
    }, 1000);
```

```css
body{
transition:background 1s linear;
}
```

background moving with the colors of the rainbow:

```css
body{
  color:white
}
```

```html
<marquee scrollamount="20" style="position:fixed;top:0;left:0;bottom:0;right:0;width:100%;height:100vh;z-index:-9999999;margin:0;padding:0">
<div style="width:200%;height:100vh;margin-left:-100%;background:linear-gradient(to left, red,orange,yellow,green,blue,indigo,violet,red,orange,yellow,green,blue,indigo,violet);"></div>
</marquee>

body body body body body body body body body body body body body body body body body
```

Answer (score 1):

try using transition-timing-function like step-start and step-end.

```
transition-timing-function: step-start;
transition-timing-function: step-end;
```

See the fiddle for understanding: https://jsfiddle.net/9bcgw7x4/5/

In the code at fiddle replace the background colours with your desired ones.

**Updated**

Comment: On jsFiddle is see CSS animations but in post you are talking about CSS transitions.

Comment: Oops my bad... Create an animation of desired colors and then apply that animation on body :)

Answer (score 1):

Below is an example of the code you're looking for. If you want it to apply to the whole page then you should add it to the body tag. I used http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/ to generate this code snippet.

```
body { /* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#6db3f2+0,f9e759+0,f9e759+0,f9e759+0,f2f257+16,e85353+16,e85353+57,4239a0+57,4239a0+57,4239a0+83,66ff5b+83,66ff5b+83 */
background: #6db3f2; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #6db3f2 0%, #f9e759 0%, #f9e759 0%, #f9e759 0%, #f2f257 16%, #e85353 16%, #e85353 57%, #4239a0 57%, #4239a0 57%, #4239a0 83%, #66ff5b 83%, #66ff5b 83%); /* FF3.6-15 */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #6db3f2 0%,#f9e759 0%,#f9e759 0%,#f9e759 0%,#f2f257 16%,#e85353 16%,#e85353 57%,#4239a0 57%,#4239a0 57%,#4239a0 83%,#66ff5b 83%,#66ff5b 83%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
background: linear-gradient(to right, #6db3f2 0%,#f9e759 0%,#f9e759 0%,#f9e759 0%,#f2f257 16%,#e85353 16%,#e85353 57%,#4239a0 57%,#4239a0 57%,#4239a0 83%,#66ff5b 83%,#66ff5b 83%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#6db3f2', endColorstr='#66ff5b',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 */ }
```

Here is an example with the colors you mentioned.

```
linear-gradient(to left, red 15%, orange 15%, orange 30%, yellow 30%, yellow 45%, green 45%, green 60%, blue 60%, blue 75%, indigo 75%, indigo 90%, violet 90%, violet)
```

Comment: From the link you provided, all I see is a blue background. So if this isn't what you're looking for that might be the cause of my misunderstanding.